# How do I add custom CSS to a streamlit expander?

Tags: python, html, css, user-interface, streamlit

I have been trying out to different methods to add a plain white background to the st.expander, and I want that the default css pattern is not applied for that widget, nothing has seemed to work so far.

```
import streamlit as st

def main():
    st.set_page_config(page_icon = '️', page_title="Chatbot", layout="wide")

    # Define a variable to store the path to the image file
    image_path = "img2.png"

    # Define custom CSS styles, including the background pattern
    custom_css = """
    <style>
        .stApp {
                --s: 82px; /* control the size */
                --c1: #b2b2b2;
                --c2: #ffffff;
                --c3: #d9d9d9;
                
                --_g: var(--c3) 0 120deg,#0000 0;
                background:
                    conic-gradient(from -60deg at 50% calc(100%/3),var(--_g)),
                    conic-gradient(from 120deg at 50% calc(200%/3),var(--_g)),
                    conic-gradient(from  60deg at calc(200%/3),var(--c3) 60deg,var(--c2) 0 120deg,#0000 0),
                    conic-gradient(from 180deg at calc(100%/3),var(--c1) 60deg,var(--_g)),
                    linear-gradient(90deg,var(--c1)   calc(100%/6),var(--c2) 0 50%,
                                        var(--c1) 0 calc(500%/6),var(--c2) 0);
                background-size: calc(1.732*var(--s)) var(--s);
        }
        
        .stApp > div:first-child {
            background: radial-gradient(#444cf7 0.5px, #e5e5f7 0.5px);
            background-size: 10px 10px;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        
        .title{
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        foreground-color: black;
        font-size: 48px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab', roboto;
        }
    </style>
    """

    st.markdown(custom_css, unsafe_allow_html=True)
    with st.markdown('<div class="title">MinerGuide ⛏️⚒️</div>', unsafe_allow_html=True):
        pass

    

    # Add custom CSS for the text_area
    text_area_css = """
    <style>
        .stTextArea {
            background-color: #d9d9d9;
            opacity: 1.0;
            border: 1px solid #6a5454;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        
    </style>
    """
    
    # Add custom CSS for the text_area
    st.markdown(text_area_css, unsafe_allow_html=True)
    question = st.text_area("Enter Your Question - ")

    if st.button(" Enter! "):
        st.info("Your Question: " + question)

        st.info("Your Answer: ")
        st.write("Generated Answer Here")
        st.write("Generated MetaData Information Here!")
    
    
    with st.expander("About the App"):
        
        st.write(
                     
            """
              
            Content for ChatBot
            """
        )

        # Display the image
        st.image(image_path, width=1070)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So far, I have tried to add the css code in custom_css variable as well and differently using a markdown for expander as well, but those methods too did not work.